# Native KDE look for Qt 5 app

Tags: linux, qt, kde-plasma, qt5

I installed Qt5 along with Qt4 on my Kubuntu 12.10 linux machine and noticed the following:

- Program compiled with Qt4 has native KDE look and feel. I use default KDE's *Oxygen* theme and so does my program (note smooth gradient with title and blue selection of focused widget);
- But when recompiled with Qt5 **without any changes to code**, it uses different style (seems like it is called *Fusion*) and it looks awkward and out-of-place (see right pic)

[image: Native look of Qt4 app][image: NOT native look of Qt5 app]

What I want is pretty straitforward: I want my app to fit surrounding system, i.e. look native always. When using Qt4, I'm used to having this by default. Qt5 also seemed to have normal native look in Windows. But what do I have to do to have the same in Kubuntu as well? And, ideally, **everywhere**? I mean, I do not want to force linux build of my app to strictly use *Oxygen*. I want it to use the theme that is currently set in KDE: just like it was in good old Qt4.

*It seems like app code is not relevant to this issue: I didn't play with any QStyle's in it, it's pretty much typical Qt's hello-world. But just in case [it's on GitHub](https://github.com/NIA/qfractal).*

**UPD:** @peppe [has given](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14880148/693538) pretty sufficient answer on *why this problem happens* (Oxygen theme in KDE is compiled against Qt4 and not usable by Qt5). **But I'm still looking for the answer on *how to fix this?*** I tried to find Oxygen theme source to play around with, but didn't find anything except [Firefox theme](http://kde-look.org/content/show.php?content=117962).

**UPD2:** @kwirz [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15965194/693538) an interesting idea: force the app to use GTK+ theme, and enable **oxygen-gtk** in KDE settings that makes GTK windows look similar to Oxygen. On the one hand, it indeed looks closer to Oxygen:

[image: Semi-native look of Qt5 app using oxygen-gtk]

But on the other hand, we already see the little differences: readonly line edit turns gray, focused button is still not hightlighted, etc. Unfortunately, when trying to apply this technique to more complex widgets, even more artifacts appear (especially on combo box and spinner):

> > [image: Artifacts on QComboBox and QTimeEdit using oxygen-gtk]

So it seems like this techique cannot be a complete solution, but still very useful is simple cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Oxygen is part of KDE, so that's where you find it. It's not a stand-alone theme. You cannot build KDE against Qt 5, it's not supported. The next major version of KDE (KDE 5) will be using Qt 5.

So right now, there's absolutely nothing you can do. If you want your application to look and behave nice in KDE 4, use Qt 4.

Comment: So there is absolutely no way to extract Oxygen as theme from KDE code, yes? I hoped I could play with it and make it build with Qt5...

Comment: @NIA Since Oxygen depends on KDE and KDE can only use Qt4, you can't make Oxygen use Qt5 since loading Qt5 and Qt4 at the same time is not possible.

Comment: Ah, got it. Will not use Qt5 in KDE until KDE 5, OK.

Comment: I thought years back, since it was required for the GTK version, Oxygen removed the dependency on kdelibs?

Comment: @JonathanBaldwin oxygen-gtk is a completely independent project form oxygen-qt, it just reimplemented all routines to access kde settings and to process kde palette etc. to be free from kdelibs dependency (and useful in e.g. XFCE without additional dependencies even on Qt). Even with Qt5 oxygen is still dependent on KDE frameworks.

Answer (score 9):

It's not your app -- it's just that Oxygen is compiled against Qt 4 and not Qt 5, so Qt 5 can't use it and falls back to the default style ("fusion"). Remember that styles are actually **plugins** -- i.e. code, subject to API/ABI requirements in order to be loaded and used. You need an Oxygen style compiled against Qt 5.

Comment: Any ideas how to get Oxygen styles compiled against Qt5 and make my app know about them?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. You should ask KDE developers about their plans :-)

Answer (score 4):

try

```
QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("GTK+"));
```

as workaround, it looks native, if oxygen-gtk is installed.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, I haven't thought about it. I've updated my question with a few lines about it.

Answer (score 1):

Start your Qt5 application with parameter:

```
-style=gtk
```

There is no global setting that i know of, that makes this for all QT5 apps.

Good luck!