# How to build KDE Oxygen plugin on Qt 5?

Tags: qt, kde-plasma

I'm moving my project from Qt 4.8.4 to Qt 5.1. On all platforms application looks native except (ironic) KDE. I know problem source - KDE oxygen style (plugin) is compiled on Qt 4.8.4 so it can't be used by Qt 5.1 . So if it is plugin problem only, then maybe building it on Qt 5.1 solve problem. I downloaded KDE Workspace module from KDE which include oxygen source. It is in `<kde workspace src>/libs/oxygen` but have no idea how to compile only just this little lib. Is anyone have oxygen plugin compiled on Qt 5.1 or know steps how to build it?

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14880032/native-kde-look-for-qt-5-app) you got a workaround using gtk theme

Comment: Yes, I know about this solution but it looks ugly in my project

Comment: Well, then you should switch to Qt 4.* for the moment...